# Seeed Respeaker speaker output is very low

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-lite, speakers

I am using ReSpeaker 4 microphone array kit with raspberry pi to get the ASR system. Respeaker mic array has its own speaker output (not the jack output) on board but the output volume is very low. How can I increment the volume to get high-volume sound?

Comment: You need a "ReSpeaker Drive Unit", its a 5Watt, 4 ohm amplifier unit. Or you need a "Active speaker".

Answer (score 2):

> has its own **speaker** output

Is it really a *speaker* output, or is it just an *audio* output?

I don't see any mention of an amplifier [here](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_4_Mic_Array_for_Raspberry_Pi/#hardware-overview), and **to drive a speaker you need an amplifier.**  You connect the respeaker to the amplifier and the amplifier to the speaker, otherwise you have an unamplified signal which is bound to be very low.

Comment: is correct the "speaker output" cant drive a passive speaker. Check out the "ReSpeaker Drive Unit" or get a active speaker.

Comment: Speakers with amplifiers built into them are very common now-a-days.  Bluetooth speakers are always such since you cannot transmit an amplified signal wirelessly, and these usually have a "line in" or "aux"(illary) jack in 3.5mm or RCA 2-channel form.